# Under a Continuous Deployment process to publish a Maven package of a Clojure project, should the script execute "lein install" or "lein uberjar"?

Tags: maven, clojure, github-actions, continuous-deployment, leiningen

I built a Continuous Deployment workflow via GitHub Actions for this [Clojure project](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase). It is a fork from a public repository.

The goal was to publish a Maven package on the GitHub Registry every time `project.clj` file gets tweaked (usually it is tweaked for version bumps).

It works. See the workflow [running smoothly](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/actions/runs/3885805008/jobs/6630139454). And the [package has been successfully published](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/packages/1769599).

As shown on the `cd.yml` file, before [the Deployment part](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/blob/a7163018b97ef53bcc6e7ecc25675d6e85804aa6/.github/workflows/cd.yml#L88) on the script, there is a `lein install` [execution on the script](https://github.com/tallyfor/re-frame-firebase/blob/a7163018b97ef53bcc6e7ecc25675d6e85804aa6/.github/workflows/cd.yml#L83).

A co-worker suggested that instead of `lein install` the command `lein uberjar` should be the one being used.

According to the official documentation:

```
lein uberjar # package the project and dependencies as standalone jar
```

And `lein install` on the other hand:

```
Install jar and pom to the local repository; typically ~/.m2.
```

1 - Under this Maven package publishing effort context, which command should be used `lein uberjar` or `lein install`? Why?

2 - Is there any disadvantage to using `lein install` instead of `lein uberjar`? It the only downside an "overkill aspect"?

3 - Also, even if `lein uberjar` is the most appropriate way on GitHub Actions, if the `cd.yml` is being used as hard-coded documentation for other developers to replicate things locally (if needed), wouldn't it be better to have maximum reproducibility? And, hence, wouldn't `lein install` be the appropriate approach instead of `lein uberjar`?

Comment: Uberjars are used to package applications with all their dependencies so users don't need to configure the classpath manually. If you're publishing a library for other developers to consume, then don't publish the uberjar. `lein` install will only create a minimal jar containing the code for your project, and list the other dependencies in the POM file. You might find using `lein deploy` easier than your current approach or `lein install` followed by publishing the jar with maven.

Comment: Thanks, @Lee! Why exactly would `lein deploy` be easier than `lein install`?

Comment: It looks like your current approach is to install the jar into your local repository, configure maven, and then use that to publish the jar. You should be able to replace all those steps with a single `lein deploy`. But your current approach should be fine if it's working for you.